# Allow user to create account on one device and use that account on others

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, user-identification

I want to make an application that has some views for information display. If I install my app on my iPhone then it should display the info. If I then install that app on my iPad then the app should recognize the device and display the info related to my account.

Is there any way to find the single user of two devices without the user's iTunes credentials, or is it possible to generate a key that can identify the common user of both devices?

Comment: More information would be helpful. Where is this information coming from? Are you accessing it via web services? Do you have any kind of user authentication already?

Comment: Actually i am also finding that is there any way to get information about the user account having two different device.

Comment: if you know the way of any authentication then please share with me.

Comment: Why do you have to rely on their iDevices? It would be easier to put together a proprietary database and have them log into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently there is no way to associate multiple devices to a single user owning those devices given the information you've provided.

However, if you added, "the information I want to display in the views, pertains to the same user account in Game Center for both devices", then you could use the player's identifier from Game Kit API.

https://developer.apple.com/game-center/

Answer (score 0):

This is being added well after the fact, but:

You could use iCloud APIs to accomplish this. These are distinct from iTunes credentials, but obviously the same type of prerequisite in that the user must have an account and it's not under your control.